# Encoding NSString cut short using NSASCIIStringEncoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, character-encoding, nsstring

I've got this:

```
<53657269 616c3a20 39303030 30303138 3b4d6f64 656c3a20 32323031 3b466972 6d776172 653a2030 3431353b 4c696272 6172793a 20535444 30363132 3b566f69 63653a20 4d31303b 546f7765 723a2059 65733b52 65636f72 643a2059 65733b44 69616c3a 204e6f3b 554f7074 733a2031 39383b46 756e6374 696f6e73 3a205245 44411034 424c5545 1011546f 6c6c0118 48796d6e a003466e 63351066 666f6f64 10556261 636f0000 746f6173 10253b4c 6162656c 733a2042 4c554542 4c554523 466e6338 544f4153 54455223 466e6337 4241434f 4e23466e 63354c41 50544f50 53235245 44415445 58415323 466e6336 42524943 4b532374 6f617354 4f415354 45522362 61636f42 41434f4e 23666f6f 64424143 4f4e3b4d 696c5665 723a2035 2e302e36 2e313b4c 6f67696e 3a205965 73>
```

I'm using this to convert to a NSString:

```
NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

My output is:

```
  Serial: 90000018;Model: 2201;Firmware: 0415;Library: STD0612;Voice: M10;Tower: Yes;Record: Yes;Dial: No;UOpts: 198;Functions: REDA4BLUETollHymn Fnc5ffoodUbaco
```

If you convert the entire set you get a lot more than what is showing up in the string. Why is it cutting it short in the encoding?

Quickly converting with readily available encoders online you get the full conversion:

```
Serial: 90000018;Model: 2201;Firmware: 0415;Library: STD0612;Voice: M10;Tower: Yes;Record: Yes;Dial: No;UOpts: 198;Functions: REDA4BLUETollHymn Fnc5ffoodUbacotoas%;Labels: BLUEBLUE#Fnc8TOASTER#Fnc7BACON#Fnc5LAPTOPS#REDATEXAS#Fnc6BRICKS#toasTOASTER#bacoBACON#foodBACON;MilVer: 5.0.6.1;Login: Yes
```

Why is NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; only writing about half to the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it's converting the whole string, but the mechanism you're using to examine it is truncating it. It looks like your ASCII-encoded data has embedded null characters in it. `NSString` is perfectly capable of holding embedded null characters, but anything which converts to a C-style string will stop processing after it hits one of those.

What do you get if you post-process your string using the following?

```
unichar nullUnichar = 0;
NSString* nullCharString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&nullUnichar length:1];
info = [info stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:nullCharString withString:@"\\x00"];
```

Comment: Either that, or try `NSUTF8StringEncoding`? *edit* Actually, that probably won't work either... the null chars need to be removed, plus it looks like the data has several "control characters" -- 0x10, 0x11, etc - that could throw the conversion off.

Comment: @DonMag: That would still end up with embedded null characters in the string and anything which did C-sting style processing on it would stop there.

Comment: @KenThomases your solution works. Filtering and replacing the the null characters allows it to print to full string. Thanks!

Comment: @KenThomases Just curious. How does one identify that there was null characters in the data. I couldn't see that with the decoder I was using for testing.

Comment: @johnsonjp34 - by quick eye scan the data at least contains `636f0000`, that's two nulls there.